# Selectnav.js not running?

Tags: iphone, navigation, responsive-design

I'm using a wordpress theme which should swap to a dropdown menu when displayed on a mobile phone. From what I can tell, selectnav.min.js has been integrated and should perform this function. I can see that the script is integrated in the header, but for some reason this is not running, but I don't know why.

http://www.sandbox.sharonblance.com/

(there is a demo version of this theme where you can see this menu in action: http://themes.tvda.eu/demos/kutcherstudio/)

Answer (score 0):

Move the selectnav.min.js to the bottom, AFTER the HTML for the nav. By having it in the <head>, the script is running prior to the nav being available in the DOM so the mobile nav menu () cannot be built because the main menu does not exist yet.

Comment: This currently being loaded using the following at the moment, which should cause this to load in the footer shouldn't it? (last variable is for $infooter = true?). wp_footer() is also being called in the footer. 
wp_enqueue_script( 'selectnav.min', THEME_DIR . '/js/selectnav.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );